# Sharepoint out of memory at line 1

Tags: sharepoint

In SharePoint 2013 (using IE8) I created a search which returned multiple pages.
I clicked each page and displayed the results.
When got to the end, used Browser Back Button to return to my site collection portal.
Then I received a warning message: "Out of memory at line 1".

If anyone can help that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this points:
1. Close anyInternet Explorer or Windows Explorer windows that are currently open.

2.Open Internet Explorer by clicking the Start button , and then clicking Internet Explorer.

3.Click the Tools button, and then click Internet Options.

4.Click the Advanced tab, and then click Reset.

5.Select the Delete personal settings check box if you would like to remove browsing history, search providers, Accelerators, home pages, and InPrivate Filtering data.

6.In the Reset Internet Explorer Settings dialog box, click Reset.

7.When Internet Explorer finishes applying default settings, click Close, and then click OK.

8.Close Internet Explorer.

9.Restart Internet Explorer.